# PHP - average column where another column is a specific name

Tags: mysql

In PHP 
How can I average a column where another column is a specific name. There will be several records for the same person in this table. I don't get any result here.

**Eg:**

```
 $result = mysqli_query($con,"Select * FROM record WHERE Name='Alex'");
 $avg = "SELECT Name='Alex', AVG(Q1) FROM record";
 $average = mysqli_query($avg);

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($average)){
 echo $row['AVG(Q1)'];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to change your query to:

```
SELECT NAME, AVG(Q1) as average FROM record where NAME='Alex' group by NAME
```

and then when you try to read the result:

```
echo $row['average'];
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
 select name, avg(Q1) as Q1_Average from record where name='Alex' group by name
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `group by` clause to find average of indivisuals:

```
$avg = "SELECT Name,AVG(Q1) FROM record group by Name";
```